# Printing out the output of a method in Junit test

Tags: java, junit

So for an assignment, we were tasked with building generic functions to handle objects. which in this case are 2 different card decks. One was your standard 52 playing card deck, the other was a deck of our choise. I chose Star Trek next Generation cards. (disclaimer, i know very little about junit test. it was never covered in my classes and what little i do know came from experimentation) Anyway, I have a method that will deal X amount of cards. I need help figuring out how to print out the output of the method in junit test. here is my code for the junit test and the method.

```
'''public void test_cardPile_dealNum() {
        aceOfHearts = new StandardCard ("Hearts", "Ace");
        aceOfDiamonds = new StandardCard ("Montrial", "Ace");
        aceOfClubs = new StandardCard("Clubs", "Ace");
        fedCaptain = new starTrekCards("Federation", "Jean Luc Picard");
        fedFirstOff = new starTrekCards("Federation","Willian Riker");
        fedDoctor = new starTrekCards("Federation", "Beverly Crusher");
        fedCounciler = new starTrekCards("Federation","Diana Troy");
        contArse = new starTrekCards ("Continuum", "Q");
        romCommander = new starTrekCards("Romulan Star Empire", "Commander Sela");
        romSupport = new starTrekCards ("Romulan Star Empire", "Kimara Cretak");
        klingLeader = new starTrekCards ("Klingon Empire", "Chancelor Garon");

        int number = 3;


    CardPile test3 =new CardPile ();
    LinkedStack Holder;

    test3.add(aceOfHearts);
    test3.add(aceOfDiamonds);
    test3.add(aceOfClubs);
    test3.add(fedCaptain);
    test3.add(fedFirstOff);
    test3.add(fedDoctor);
    test3.add(fedCounciler);
    test3.add(contArse);
    test3.add(romCommander);
    test3.add(romSupport);
    test3.add(klingLeader);

    Holder = test3.dealNumb(3);

    System.out.println(Holder.toString());
    }''''
```

and my method

'''

```
public LinkedStack<T> dealNumb(int number)
 {
     if(!card.isEmpty()){
     LinkedStack<T> cardTwo = new LinkedStack<T>(); 
     for(int i = 0; i< number; i++)
     {
        T count = card.top();
        card.pop();

        cardTwo.push(count);
     }
     return cardTwo;
 }
     else {
         return null;
         }
     }'''
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your purpose for printing out the result?

Comment: Its to show the method works,

Answer (score 0):

There's an old saying that always bears repeating :

> Anything that relies on human reliability is inherently unreliable.

Everybody makes mistakes - You, me, everybody.   When you run the test above, you are relying on your human reliability to spot any output that differs from what should be expected.   That's unreliable, and bugs will get through (not to mention painfully boring for you ! )

The power of unit tests (such as JUnit) is that they are automated.  In business, they often run entirely unattended, built into the build process that runs automatically in the background on some server machine every time anybody commits some piece of code.

As such, the tests are not for displaying the results for humans to check, but rather the test checks the results itself, typically through "Assert" statements.  You'll find Junit has a few of these ("AssertThat", "AssertEquals", etc), and Hamcrest is also useful (see http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/ )

So, instead of your `println`, what you want to do instead is assert that you have been given the three cards you expect, and that these are no longer in your CardPile - eg :

```
// nb variable names like "holder" should start with lower-case
AssertThat(holder, is(equalTo(List.of(romCommander, romSupport, klingLeader))));
AssertThat(test3.size(), is(equalTo(8))));
AssertThat(test3.pop(), is(equalTo(contArse))));
```

(btw, the `is(equalTo(List.of` may not work with whatever your implementation of LinkedStack is, but hopefully you get the idea :) )

Also, personally I always prefer `AssertThat` over `AssertEquals` as it's more readable, as well as avoiding a common mistake where people write things like stuff like :

```
AssertEquals(test3.size(), 3);
```

which is the wrong way around !   The expected result should come first, so it should be :

```
AssertEquals(3, test3.size());
```

.... but better to stick with `AssertThat`